# Using `r` with String Literals in Python

Tags: python

I'm slightly confused over what `r` actually does and haven't been able to make sense of other explanations associated with it. For example, what is the difference between `s1` and `s2`:

```
s1 = r'this\\has\no\special\characters'
```

**Edit:**

```
s2 = 'this\\has\no\special\characters'
```

Thanks

Comment: those are 100% same i think you need remove `r` at the first of one of them

Comment: Did you mean to leave off a `\ ` in `s2`?

Comment: If you drop the `r` from one, you'll see the difference.

Comment: The `r` denotes a raw string so essentially special/control characters don't need escaping, however if you use this as a path then it will not handle trailing back slashes I believe so you need to be careful

Comment: You could easily tell by just printing them, the second string will treat the `\n` as a new line character whilst in the first string it isn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `s1` has 2 backslashes between "this" and "has" and `s2` only has 1. Also, `s2` picks up a newline at the `\n` whereas `s1` does not.  The difference becomes very clear if you print the strings.

Basically, with `r` in front of a string literal, what you see is what you get<sup>1</sup>.  Without `r` in front, python will translate various escape codes (`\t`, `\n`, `\\`, etc) into different characters (tab, newline, \, etc.)

<sup><sup>1</sup>There is 1 gotcha that I know of ... `r'\'` is a `SyntaxError` ...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can see that in the first case the `r` makes it a raw string so the slashes and any control characters are handled correctly (in the first case you now have a double slash), compare with string 2 where the `\n` now becomes a new line:

```
In [218]:

s1 = r'this\\has\no\special\characters'
print(s1)
s2 = 'this\\has\no\special\characters'
print(s2)
this\\has\no\special\characters
this\has
o\special\characters
```

Something to be careful of is using raw strings for building a path, if the path contains a trailing back slash then this will not be handled:

```
In [220]:

path = r'c:\mytemp\'
  File "<ipython-input-220-ca80e74afea4>", line 1
    path = r'c:\mytemp\'
                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Answer (score 0):

the first one (`s1`) is a regular expressions set and second just is a string ! and based on the `python doc` :

Regular expressions use the backslash character `('\')` to indicate special forms or to allow special characters to be used without invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write `'\\\\'` as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be `\\`, and each backslash must be expressed as `\\` inside a regular Python string literal.

The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with `'r'`. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation.
so you have :

```
>>> s1 = r'this\\has\no\special\characters'
>>> s1
'this\\\\has\\no\\special\\characters'
>>> s2 = 'this\\has\no\special\characters'
>>> s2
'this\\has\no\\special\\characters'
```