# Concat string in column values where it is missing in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
data_as_dict={'CHROM': {2241743: 21, 2241744: 3, 2241745: 5, 2241746: 6, 2241747: 6, 2241748: 11, 2241749: 16, 2241750: 20, 0: 'chr1', 1: 'chr2', 2: 'chr3', 3: 'chr5', 4: 'chr5', 5: 'chr8', 6: 'chr9', 7: 'chr10', 8: 'chr14', 9: 'chr14', 10: 'chr15', 11: 'chr15'}, 'POS_GRCh38': {2241743: 41668857, 2241744: 189487243, 2241745: 33946466, 2241746: 396321, 2241747: 32641081, 2241748: 89284793, 2241749: 89960104, 2241750: 34077942, 0: '233276815', 1: '217427435', 2: '169800667', 3: '1279675', 4: '112150207', 5: '32575278', 6: '97775520', 7: '103934543', 8: '36063370', 9: '36269155', 10: '67165147', 11: '67163292'}, 'REF': {2241743: 'T', 2241744: 'A', 2241745: 'A', 2241746: 'C', 2241747: 'C', 2241748: 'G', 2241749: 'T', 2241750: 'G', 0: 'G', 1: 'G', 2: 'G', 3: 'C', 4: 'T', 5: 'T', 6: 'C', 7: 'C', 8: 'C', 9: 'C', 10: 'G', 11: 'C'}, 'Effect_allele': {2241743: 'A', 2241744: 'T', 2241745: 'G', 2241746: 'T', 2241747: 'T', 2241748: 'A', 2241749: 'C', 2241750: 'A', 0: 'A', 1: 'C', 2: 'T', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'G', 6: 'A', 7: 'T', 8: 'G', 9: 'T', 10: 'C', 11: 'T'}, 'Effect_size': {2241743: 0.094310679, 2241744: 0.122217633, 2241745: 0.527632769, 2241746: 0.482426149, 2241747: 0.157003749, 2241748: 0.148420005, 2241749: 0.285178942, 2241750: 0.2390169, 0: 0.2776317365982795, 1: 0.3576744442718159, 2: 0.2070141693843261, 3: 0.1823215567939546, 4: 0.3148107398400336, 5: 0.2776317365982795, 6: 0.5247285289349821, 7: 0.3435897043900768, 8: 0.3293037471426003, 9: 0.5933268452777344, 10: 0.2070141693843261, 11: 0.2151113796169455}, 'TYPE': {2241743: 'Basal_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241744: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241745: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241746: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241747: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241748: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241749: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 2241750: 'Squamous_cell_carcinoma_PRSWeb', 0: 'THYROID_PGS', 1: 'THYROID_PGS', 2: 'THYROID_PGS', 3: 'THYROID_PGS', 4: 'THYROID_PGS', 5: 'THYROID_PGS', 6: 'THYROID_PGS', 7: 'THYROID_PGS', 8: 'THYROID_PGS', 9: 'THYROID_PGS', 10: 'THYROID_PGS', 11: 'THYROID_PGS'}, 'Cancer': {2241743: 'NMSC', 2241744: 'NMSC', 2241745: 'NMSC', 2241746: 'NMSC', 2241747: 'NMSC', 2241748: 'NMSC', 2241749: 'NMSC', 2241750: 'NMSC', 0: 'THYROID', 1: 'THYROID', 2: 'THYROID', 3: 'THYROID', 4: 'THYROID', 5: 'THYROID', 6: 'THYROID', 7: 'THYROID', 8: 'THYROID', 9: 'THYROID', 10: 'THYROID', 11: 'THYROID'}, 'Significant_YN': {2241743: 'Y', 2241744: 'Y', 2241745: 'Y', 2241746: 'Y', 2241747: 'Y', 2241748: 'Y', 2241749: 'Y', 2241750: 'Y', 0: 'Y', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Y', 3: 'Y', 4: 'Y', 5: 'Y', 6: 'Y', 7: 'Y', 8: 'Y', 9: 'Y', 10: 'Y', 11: 'Y'}}

all_cancers = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_as_dict)
```

I want to append string `chr` in column `CHROM` where it's missing. I can do it in R with `grepl` and `paste`, but wanted to try in Python.
I came up with these two commands, but not sure how to index the column because pd.Series is generating NaNs.

```py
pd.Series(all_cancers['CHROM']).str.contains(pat = 'chr', regex = True)
"chr" + all_cancers['CHROM'].map(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String operations in pandas are not optimized, so the best way to do what you want is via a list comprehension.

```py
# check if a value contains 'chr' and prepend it if not
all_cancers['CHROM'] = [x if isinstance(x, str) and 'chr' in x else f"chr{x}" for x in all_cancers['CHROM'].tolist()]
```

An equivalent pandas operation could be via `mask()` method.

```py
# flag rows that starts with 'chr' and prepend 'chr' to values in the remaining rows 
all_cancers['CHROM'] = all_cancers['CHROM'].mask(~all_cancers['CHROM'].str.startswith('chr', na=False), 'chr'+all_cancers['CHROM'].astype(str))
```

A simple `timeit` test would show that the list comp is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

### Regex replace with backreference

Using [`pandas.Dataframe.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) to *prepend* conditionally:

- enable `regex` search-and-replace
- search by: regex condition, starting with a number
- replace by: prepend your prefix `chr` and reinsert first captured group, the number `(\d+)`, using backreference `\1`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# minimal example
data_as_dict = {
    'CHROM': {2241743: 21, 0: 'chr1'},
    'POS_GRCh38': {2241743: 41668857, 0: '233276815'},
    'REF': {2241743: 'T', 0: 'G'}
}

# rename dataframe variable to shorter and common df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_as_dict)

# regex-replace a column:
#  (a) convert numbers to string
#  (b) where starting with number, prepend 'chr', reinsert captured number
df['CHROM'] = df['CHROM'].astype(str).replace(r'^(\d+)', r'chr\1', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Notes:

- since the replace function requires a string as input, we need to convert the number-type values first using `astype(str)`
- the *raw-string* prefix `r` before string literals here assures correct regex-interpretation to prevent escaping. Without this `\1` will end up as unprintable control-character for ASCII code 1

#### Output

Given input before:

```
         CHROM POS_GRCh38 REF
2241743     21   41668857   T
0         chr1  233276815   G
```

Expected output after prepending:

```
         CHROM POS_GRCh38 REF
2241743  chr21   41668857   T
0         chr1  233276815   G
```

#### ️ See also

- [How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196203/how-to-conditionally-update-dataframe-column-in-pandas)
- [Using regex matched groups in pandas dataframe replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472951/using-regex-matched-groups-in-pandas-dataframe-replace-function)
- [Using `r` with String Literals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163798/using-r-with-string-literals-in-python)

For using a regular expression (regex) to prepend/append or reinsert see:

- [Reinserting Text Matched By Capturing Groups in The Replacement Text](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)

### ️ Hint on terminology

- [prepend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepend): add a prefix at the beginning of astring
- [append](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append): add a suffix at the end of a string
- concat or [concatenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation): join two or more strings end-to-end

Illustrated: [Append Vs. Prepend. What’s The Difference? | by Elle D | Medium](https://ellecodes.medium.com/append-vs-prepend-whats-the-difference-97ce457f675c)

Comment: It is not giving the correct answer. It is only inserting chr, but not concatenating chr with numbers.

Comment: @MAPK Thanks for pointing out the misunderstood requirement. Fixed it: Will now _prepend_ numbers with 'chr'. Conditional insertion is applied using regex-replace with backreference.